# Excel VBA: form control listbox with multi-columns -- how to populate from ADO recordset?

Tags: excel, vba, controls

Due to compatibility issues, I am having to use an Excel **form control listbox** (vs. ActiveX) control on my spreadsheet. I am trying to populate it with three fields from an ADO recordset, but I am having problems as it has been sometime since I have used Form Controls.

Here is the code I wrote for my ActiveX listbox. Can you point me to an example of where a form control listbox with multiple columns is populated from an ADO recordset?

Thanks ahead of time for any help you can provide in making this conversion!

-- Tom

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
 On Error GoTo Err_Worksheet_Activate
 Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
 Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
 Dim i As Integer

     Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

     cnn.ConnectionString = gcstr_Connection ' a global property with the connection string defined elsewhere. The connection is to a SQL Server database.

      cnn.Open

      Set rst = cnn.Execute("SELECT [FieldA], [FieldB], [FieldC] FROM dbo.", , adCmdText)

      rst.MoveFirst

      With Me.lst_System
          .Clear
          Do
          .AddItem
          .List(i, 0) = rst![FieldA]
          .List(i, 1) = rst![FieldB]
          .List(i, 2) = rst![FieldC]
          i = i + 1
              rst.MoveNext
          Loop Until rst.EOF
      End With

 Exit_Worksheet_Activate:
      On Error Resume Next
      rst.Close
      cnn.Close
      Set rst = Nothing
      Set cnn = Nothing
      Exit Sub

 Err_Worksheet_Activate:
      MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
      Err.Clear
      Resume Exit_Worksheet_Activate
 End Sub
```

Comment: I forgot to add, this listbox is on a spreadsheet, not inside a Userform.

Answer (score 0):

No idea if Form control can support muticolumns like the ActiveX list box so you might need to consider adding  them in differently..

Below is an example of how to remove all/add items, hope it helps:

```
'to remove all previous items
Me.Shapes("lst_System").ControlFormat.RemoveAllItems
'to add item
Me.Shapes("lst_System").ControlFormat.AddItem "SomeStringValue"
```